# Unable to login through Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I was trying to integrate Facebook SDK into an Android app with the help of official tutorial provided on [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/). I have followed all the steps correctly and my application contains no compilation errors. But when I try to test it on a live device I am getting the error as follows:

```
The page you requested cannot be displayed right now. It may be temporarily unavailable, the link you clicked might be broken or expired, or you may have not the permission to view this page.
```

I am not able to understand the reason for this error. Please help!

Code:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.myfbapp;

import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback(){

        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            if(session.isOpened()){
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        if(user!=null){
                            TextView tvWelcome=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvWelcome);
                            tvWelcome.setText("Welcome "+user.getName()+"!");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvWelcome"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Welcome!" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myfbapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfbapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:value="@string/app_id" android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"/>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: have you disabled Sandbox mode on facebook developers page in Basic info module?

Comment: Yes! I have disabled Sandbox mode.

Comment: Better u try to put this code on button click...try with that...

Comment: Still the same response!

Comment: Are you sure that all the required details on facebook page filled correctly?

Comment: According to me, everything appears to be correct. I have seen in one of the questions here that the hash key does not contain "=" (equals) at the end, is it right?

Comment: my hashkey is like  abCd1qqGrBB3XYI27FN6nlrEl9U

Comment: My hash key is like Q+DL/p1l+3C+nOjtjat2USa789Q, there was an "=" (equals) at the end, I removed that, still it's giving the same response.

Answer (score 1):

**Updating the Facebook app on your device may solve the problem**,

It may not work if the Facebook app is not updated.
I had the same issue and updating solved it